# Loudness Equalization on input devices (i.e Microphone)?

Tags: windows-10

I'm wondering if there's a way to get Loudness Equalization functionality (capping the volume on a device to some range) on my microphone, the same way I can on my speakers. Is this possible, and if so, in Windows directly or with third-party software?

Comment: FYI this is called an `Audio Compressor Filter` or just `compressor.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply a DSP to my microphone in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/410415/apply-a-dsp-to-my-microphone-in-windows)